# Avro DataFileWriter API with confluent schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

Can I use avro DataFileWriter with schema registry?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write files into the registry, so, not really.

You can use DataFileReader to get a schema and POST to the Registry.

You can use Registry to get a different schema than the one included in the file (for example, you're doing schema evolution)